# Cache with annotations, Mapkit and regions

Tags: ios, caching, mapkit, mkannotation

I have a question about MapKit.
I have to visualize annotations on map and I downloaded these from a server.

I would to implement an efficient cache system.

My idea is this: 
I can mantain an array of Regions an when the user make a pan on the map I have to calculate the new region..

If this region is contained into a my regions list I can visualize the annotations otherwise I have to request the new region  to the server.

How can I calculate the region when the user make a pan on the map?

Are there some methods to calculate if the region is contained into other region?

Are there some example project about this idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for per-map ID, but there is `-[RMTileCache removeAllCachedImagesForCacheKey:]`. You can construct a given `cacheKey` for a tile source if you have a look at how it is made in that tile source's code.